# chomp and replace in all string in array in Perl efficiently

Tags: regex, perl, loops

At the moment I am reading lines from a file, chomp them, and replace tabs by spaces, like so:

```
open( my $xpfh, '<', $xpathfile ) or die "cannot open file $xpathfile";
    chomp( my @xplines = <$xpfh> );
    close $xpfh;

    foreach my $xpline (@xplines) {
        $xpline =~ s/\t/ /g;
...
```

As you can see, chomping happens outside the foreach loop, but substitution occurs each iteration. How would one bring that action outside the foreach loop, closer to the chomping? I am asking because I would assume that this is faster than each iteration run a regular expression. Either way, it would be syntactically more pleasing to have all structural operations happen in the same block.

Comment: Slurping entire file is already enifficient as long as you deal with non-trivial sizes. You might want to read line-by-line and move `chomp` into that loop too instead.

Comment: Example input/output would be good;

Comment: How do you know that it's inefficient? Have you benchmarked it?

Comment: @MattJacob No, that's why I am asking

Comment: My point is, don't assume it's inefficient until you have reason to believe it is. What you're doing is called premature optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do it *without* slurping the file into an array, then iterating the array:

```
while ( <$xpfh> ) {
    chomp;
    s/\t/ /g;
    print;
}
```

If you do need the array for some other reason though:

```
s/\t/ /g for @xplines;
```